# SQL Computed Column Dynamic datediff

Tags: mysql

I have one column of dates and wish to calculate a second column that shows the time difference in minutes between all dates. Example below.

```
time_stamp                diff_in_minutes
2022-09-23 18:40:00.000         --
2022-09-23 18:45:00.000         5
```

My problem is that the query needs to be dynamic for any time_stamp column size. I don't think/am not sure that datediff can be used this way.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `LAG()` window function to refer to the previous row and calculate the difference between the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future, Barmar comment was a big help.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, lag(time_stamp, 1, 0) over(), time_stamp)
```